# Magnifier tool for Windows with more options than the built-in magnifier tool

Tags: windows, gratis, user-interface, display, accessibility

I'm looking for a "Magnifier" freeware for Windows, that offers more customization that the built-in magnifier:

[image]

I'd like to be able to customize the shortcuts, the smoothness / speed of the zooming-in motion, and if possible no pixelization when zoomed (Windows can probably handle this by temporarily changing the resolution?)

Something that allows the user to do beautiful dynamic zooms like in [this video](https://blackmagic.so/assets/demo.mp4) (done with MacOS here).

See also [Zoom / magnify tool at the cursor's position](https://superuser.com/questions/1704041/zoom-magnify-tool-at-the-cursors-position).

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, apart from the Windows one, it is from softwareok.com called [One Loupe](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/OneLoupe)

It is a very handy solution and surely you are interested in. It has many features (it is portable for example), and the one you are asking for is this::

[image]